# When optimizing for coins, should I stock the 3-coin items first or the 1-coin items?

Tags: tiny-tower

Each business has items that sell for 1, 2, and 3 coins. The more coins they sell for, the longer it takes to stock.

If I want to optimize to get the most money possible, should I stock the 1-coin items or the 3-coin items first?

If I stock the 1-coin items first, then it will get stock on the floor quickly, but if I stock the 3-coin items first, then I'm making more money from the stock even though it takes longer and the store won't be making money during that time.

Answer (score 2):

You always want to do from most expensive to least. First of all, what that guy said is nonsense. The stock sells either way, so even if you are checking constantly, you would still be making money off of the stock. Now here is the real reason:

Since the largest items last the longest on the shelves, stocking from highest to lowest will make it easier to fully stock the entire store, giving you coin and bux benefits.

So yah, always 3 to 1

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how often you play.

Generally, the most optimal way is to stock cheapest-to-expensive. In some cases the cheap one will sell out before the expensive one has even finished stocking. This works best when you can constantly check the game to restock your items.

However if you're only occasionally checking (if you're at work for example), then it would be better to stock the more expensive ones since they will net you the most income for the least amount of time actually spent in game.